# How to know what the units are if a unity exists in a set

Tags: abstract-algebra

For example, M=$\mathbb{Q}$, a*b=$\frac{1}{2}$ab. I found that a unity exists and that the unity is 2. But I got marked off points on my homework for not writing what the units are. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: When does $\frac{4}{a}$ make sense?

Comment: anytime a isn't equal to 0. Why $\frac{4}{a}$?

Comment: Then $\frac{4}{a}*a=2$, so $a$ is a unit.

Comment: Maybe reproduce the exact instructions? I have no idea what's going on, let alone why it should matter if you've written "the units" (What do we have here, a ring? Is addition standard? What's going on??)

Comment: @pjs36 presumably they're defining a ring on the rationals with the usual addition and this alternative multiplication. I'm guessing one of the questions was just "find the units in this ring"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are trying to find $(a,b)$ such that $a*b = e$, where $e$ is the identity element, right? Well, this *is* an *algebra* course, after all, right? :)

In your specific example, you want to find all $(a,b)$ such that $a * b = e$, where $e$ is the identity element.  But as you correctly pointed out, the identity element of $(\Bbb Q, *)$ is $2$, so we want to find $(a,b)$ such that $a * b = 2$, i.e., $\frac{1}{2}ab = 2$.  Since $\frac{1}{2}ab$ is using the usual multiplication on $\Bbb Q$, we can use some regular *algebra* to find that, given any nonzero rational number $a$, its unit is $b = \frac{4}{a}$ (I just solved for $b$ in $\frac{1}{2}ab = 2$).

Comment: So if another question says M=$\mathbb{R}$, a*b=a+b-ab then my unity=0 and b=$\frac{-a}{1-a}$. So my units are any number except for 1?

Comment: @ematth7 That's right!  Since the identity element is $0$, and you want to find given any $a$, which $b$ gives us $a * b = 0$, then we want $a + b - ab = 0$, i.e., $b - ab = -a$, i.e., $b = \frac{-a}{1 - a}$, and so as long as $a \neq 1$, we can find an inverse (which is given by the above formula).